intelliJ shows wrong coverage directory in Tools window Coverage

I'm using:
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-232.10203.10, built on October 24, 2023

As you can see IntelliJ is showing the src/main/generated/package directory instead of src/main/java/package directory with my written code.
How I could change the Tools Window Coverage?
Here somo screen of my settings!


Thanks in Advance!!!

The generated folder is included in your project's classpath(compile and run), so the coverage engine will calculate any class it used in the finally running Java process.
You may try to use the coverage settings in the run configuration to exclude classes that you don't want to see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.2/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#code_coverage

